# Angular: How to create dynamic dropdown menu in a nested loop

Tags: angular, dropdown, ngfor

I am having quite some trouble figuring out how to make a dropdown menu in angular which directly shows what the user selected. I want to create cards and each card should contain a dropdown menu with the (shuffled) values.

Cars is a JSON string and the shuffle function returns a shuffled array of the corresponding keys. My code currently looks like this:

```html
<div class="row">
   <div *ngFor="let item of cars| keyvalue" class="card bg-light col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-2">
      <p class="card-text">
         {{ item.value }}
      </p>
      <div class="form-group col-5">
         <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "dropSelect">
         <option *ngFor='let car of shuffle(cars); let i = index'  selected ="selected" [attr.id]="'Drop' + i">{{car}}</option>
         </select> 
         <p>Selected option: {{dropSelect}}</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

At the moment when I select an item from the dropdown, the "selected option" part shows the selection on all other cards as well but I only want to show it for the card where the item is selected.

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Reproducible Example to speed up the process of helping you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Well, all your select boxes are bound to a single, unique variable: dropSelect. If you want each select to have its own selected value, you need one variable per select, i.e. one variable per item. So basically either an array of selected values, or a property of the item, or a separate component for each item.

Comment: @JB Nizet thanks for your answer, that makes sense. Unfortunately I do not really know how to do that, is there an easy way?

Comment: I thnk your suggestion would work but I am trying since yesterday and can't come up with a solution... There must be some way to give every card a unique dropSelect object or list or whatever but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

use [value] instead of [selected] . it may work.

you can check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamicexamples)

Comment: When I change it to liek that, it doesn't show anything anymore :/

Comment: check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamicexamples this may help i guess